# favourite tags on question page?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-watching

The side panel on a question page has "Related", "hot network questions", etc. links.
And when you're on a question page and want to view questions for a favourite tag, you need to go back to question list and click on a favourite tag. Would anyone else like to have favourite tags on the side panel on a question page? I'd be using those links often the way I'm using the site, sometimes I'll check a few questions that sound interesting which I know little about, and then want to jump straight to a favourite tag questions, without going to question page first. I know it's just one more click but does anyone else think it'd be useful?

Edit: I had a look at the question noted as duplicate. That question is mainly about moving the favourite tags higher on the side panel. It mentions having the favourite tags on a question page, but there're no answers about it, except someone suggested what I suggest here in a comment under an answer.

Comment: you only need to go back to the main page if the question you're currently viewing does not include the tag you've favorited - otherwise you can click the tag in the question. I wouldn't mind a favorite tags section on a question page so +1. The favorites tags could also be added to the page with all the questions for specific tag for an easier navigation around the site.